# Most efficient way to update Dataframe with JSON array from WebService

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I have a `code` column which I would like to pass to a web service and update two fields in the dataframe (`dfMRD1['Cache_Ticker']`and `dfMRD1['Cache_Product']` with two values from the returned JSON (`RbcSecurityDescription` and `RbcSecurityType1`). I have achieved this by iteration but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it?

```
# http://postgre01:5002/bond/912828XU9

import requests
url = 'http://postgre01:5002/bond/'

def fastquery(code):
    response = requests.get(url + code)
    return response.json()
```

Here is the sample return call:

[image]

Here is the update of `dfMRD1['Cache_Ticker']`and`dfMRD1['Cache_Product']`

```
dfMRD1 = df[['code']].drop_duplicates()
dfMRD1['Cache_Ticker'] = ""
dfMRD1['Cache_Product'] = ""
for index, row in dfMRD1.iterrows():
    result = fastquery(row['code'])
    row['Cache_Ticker'] = result['RbcSecurityDescription']        
    row['Cache_Product'] = result['RbcSecurityType1']          
display(dfMRD1.head(5))
```

[image]

Would it be best to just return the json array, unest it and dump all fields in its contents to another df which I can be join with `dfMRD1`?  Best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most time-consuming part of your code is likely to be in making synchronous requests. Instead, you could leverage [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) to make asynchronous requests, construct the columns as lists of results and assign back to the DF. We have nothing to test with but the approach would look like this:

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession(max_workers = 10)
codes = df[['code']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist() # Take out of DF
url = 'http://postgre01:5002/bond/'

fire_requests = [session.get(url + code) for code in codes] # Async requests
responses = [item.result() for item in fire_requests] # Grab the results

dfMRD1['Cache_Ticker'] = [result['RbcSecurityDescription']
                          for result in responses]
dfMRD1['Cache_Product'] = [result['RbcSecurityType1']
                           for result in responses]
```

Depending on the size of the DF, you may get a lot of data in memory. If that becomes an issue, you'll want a [background callback](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures#working-in-the-background) trimming your JSON responses as they come back.

Comment: Hey @roganjosh, getting an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_futures'

Comment: @PeterLucas it's not part of the standard library, you need to [install it](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures#installation)

Comment: ah ok!! Install now, checking